# Use of std::move in parameter construction

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I'm trying to construct an object from a function and later pass it to a function that uses it (and consumes it). Here's the code

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> createObject() {
  auto myobj = std::make_unique<Object>();
  .. modify myobj ..
  return std::move(myobj);
}

void consumeObject(std::unique_ptr<Object>&& robj) {
  myvector.emplace_back(std::forward<std::unique_ptr<Object>>(robj));
}


consumeObject(createObject()); // Is this right?
```

I'm not using rvalue references directly from the `createObject` since I would return a reference to deallocated memory.

Is `std::move` necessary in the part indicated in the code? What happens if, like I did in the code above, I pass a rvalue to be bound to the rvalue reference? The code seems to compile just fine but I can't see the difference between a

```
consumeObject(createObject());
```

and

```
consumeObject(std::move(createObject()));
```

Comment: Your code is wrong: `createObject` returns a `unique_ptr<Object>`, but `consumeObject` takes an `Object`. Can you fix that?

Comment: The move in `return std::move(myobj);` forbids NRVO, simply do `return myobj;`.

Comment: @Angew Yes, sorry. I forgot a part while making this a simple mcve

Comment: You're supposed to actually test with the MCVE. Otherwise what's the point in it? (For the record, this isn't a MCVE.)

Comment: `std::forward` makes zero sense in this context (*and* you forgot to change its template argument in the question). A `std::move` would do.

Comment: @Angew oh, I thought I had to use it when "forwarding" rvalue references to other functions that accept rvalue references

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mostly wanted to joke. I'm very bored and disheartened by my ignorance with move semantics

Comment: Well next time you want to joke please do so in some other way.

Comment: @Dean `std::forward` is for forwarding references only; see [bames53's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33999504/1782465) for some more details.

Comment: @Angew Thanks, I'm trying to clear out some confusion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999565/why-stdforward-is-useless-in-this-context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> createObject() {
  auto myobj = std::make_unique<Object>();
  .. modify myobj ..
  return std::move(myobj);
}
```

You don't need `std::move` to return a local, move-only object by value.

```
void consumeObject(std::unique_ptr<Object>&& robj) {
  myvector.emplace_back(std::forward<std::unique_ptr<Object>>(robj));
}
```

It doesn't make sense* to use `std::forward` except when you're using so-called "forwarding references", which you're not here. Just having `&&` doesn't mean you should use `std::forward`. Also you don't need `&&` here at all.

```
consumeObject(createObject()); // Is this right?
```

Yes.

---

Here's what the code probably should look like instead. Note that you mostly avoid any C++11 specific syntax and instead the code looks pretty much the same as passing a copyable object around by value. There's only one place here that anything new is necessary.

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> createObject() {
  auto myobj = std::make_unique<Object>();
  .. modify myobj ..
  return myobj;
}

void consumeObject(std::unique_ptr<Object> robj) {
  myvector.emplace_back(std::move(robj));
}


consumeObject(createObject());
```

---

* Both `std::forward` and `std::move` are just casts and the way you use `std::forward` here happens to work out to the correct cast to get a move construction. However for the sake of readability one should only use `std::move` to move and only use `std::forward` to forward.

Comment: Thanks, also a follow-up (different question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997586/use-of-stdmove-in-parameter-construction/

Answer (score 8):

`std::move` doesn't do anything magic, it just casts the argument to an rvalue.

Since `createObject` returns by value, `createObject()` is already an rvalue (specifically a prvalue), so `std::move` is unnecessary in this case and you can safely omit it.

Comment: Once again the utterly blobtastic naming choice for `std::move` strikes.