# Why is std::forward useless in this context

Tags: c++

It has come to my attention that `std::forward` is useless in this context:

```
void consumeObject(std::unique_ptr<Object>&& robj) {
  myvector.emplace_back(std::forward<std::unique_ptr<Object>>(robj));
}
```

Why is that? I thought that by the time an rvalue reference binds to a function parameter (i.e. I can reference it by name) it becomes an lvalue in that scope and in order to be passed forward needs to be casted to an rvalue reference (as in perfect forwarding).

Why is it wrong/useless?

Comment: "Casting to rvalue reference" is not "perfect forwarding". It's *moving*.

Comment: Perfect forwarding is the combination of a special template argument deduction rule and reference collapsing.

Comment: Also: perfect forwarding involves "universal references", and you don't have a universal reference; you have an rvalue reference. `std::move` is sufficient here.

Comment: Is the difference between std::move and std::forward purely **semantic**? I.e. they are implemented in the same way and they do exactly the same thing but are meant to be used in two different contexts (hence the two names)?

Comment: I agree. In this case, `std::move` would have made *better* sense, though `std::forward` produces the same *move* effect, just that it is *misleading* to the reader, in that sense it is *wrong*.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9671749 and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/13219484.

Comment: @Dean No, the implementation differs. `std::move` is intended to be used without an explicitly specified template argument, and it's not immediately obvious what happens if you do specify it. `std::forward` is deliberately designed so that it *requires* an explicit template argument.

Comment: @Simple, it's called a [forwarding reference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf), not a universal reference, please use the new and approved name.

Comment: @JonathanWakely ok. I don't like the name universal reference anyway, that's why I quoted it.

Comment: @Simple, lots of people didn't like it, that's why a better name was found, and added to the C++ working draft :) (see the link I added to my previous comment for the history)

Comment: @Dean, `std::move` always casts to an rvalue reference, but `std::forward<T>` sometimes casts to an lvalue reference and sometimes casts to an rvalue reference, depending on the template argument `T`. That difference is very important! The whole point of `std::move` is to convert to an rvalue. The whole point of `std::forward` is to convert back to the original value category of the object before you bound a forwarding reference to it. So they do not do the same thing.

Comment: What is `myvector` in this example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not *wrong* to use `std::forward` here (per se), but it is inappropriate and thus misleading (in that sense, you could say that it *is* actually wrong).

The way you spell "cast something to an rvalue reference to its type" is `std::move`. That is the *only* thing that `std::move` does—it's a `static_cast<T&&>` where you don't have to spell out the `T`.

`std::forward` is a different beast, intended for use with *perfect forwarding.* Perfect forwarding only occurs in templates, where *forwarding references* are possible. A forwarding reference is a reference which, thanks to a special rule in the language, can deduce to either an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference. There, you need `std::forward<T>` to re-instate the appropriate value category (lvalue or rvalue).

Toy example:

```
void print(int &)
{
  std::cout << "Lvalue\n";
}

void print(int &&)
{
  std::cout << "Rvalue\n";
}

template <class T>
void perfectForwarder(T &&v)
{
  print(std::forward<T>(v));
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  perfectForwarder(i);
  perfectForwarder(std::move(i));
  perfectForwarder(42);
}
```

The output will be:

> Lvalue
>   Rvalue
>   Rvalue

[[Live]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/112ac4a17623f0b6)

Comment: I would say that `std::forward` definitely is wrong here, in the same way that  unreadable code is wrong regardless of whether it works or not.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it!

Comment: I'd not say it is *"unnecessary"*. It is rather *misleading* (to the reader).

Comment: It would be nice to elaborate a bit more on what perfect forwarding is here and that this restricts forwarding rvalue as an lvalue, which will result in compile time error.

Comment: @Angew: Saw the update, but again, it is "misleading" not *because* it is "unnecessary", rather because it is *inappropriate*. The appropriate tool is `std::move` here.

Comment: @g24l Perfect forwarding, by itself, has little to do with compile-time errors. Indeed, in my toy example, omitting `std::forward` would *not* result in an error. All `std::forward` does is, as the answer states, "re-instate the appropriate value category"

Comment: @Angew check the comments in the question, they elaborate more than I will ever be able to in this comment.

Comment: @Angew: I edited the answer. Hope you dont mind that.

Comment: By the way, don't get me wrong it is not needed here, because the function is not templates, so the use case for forward will not happen in the example code.

Comment: @Nawaz No. I just re-worded the edit slightly; hope you don't mind *that* ;-)